# Disable a button based on Retrofit response

Tags: android, button, boolean, retrofit

I want to check boolean value that come from server. If boolean is true, I want to disable button click. Otherwise, can click button. I add all data from server to *rest* using Retrofit.

**@ api**

```
"bookmarked": true
```

**@ Restaurant Object**

```
private boolean bookmarked;

    public boolean isBookmarked() {
        return bookmarked;
    }
    public void setBookmarked(boolean bookmarked) {
        this.bookmarked = bookmarked;
    }
```

**@ onCreate()**

```
Restaurant rest;
Button btn;

    @Override
    public void success(Restaurant restaurant, Response response) {
        rest = restaurant;
    }

    if (rest.isBookmarked()) {
        btn.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
```

Comment: Please see about a [mcve]. What you have is three out-of-context blocks of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change the click listener based on the flag; instead, call `setEnabled(boolean)`:

```
btn.setEnabled(!rest.isBookmarked());
```

I don't quite understand the structure of your code block labeled "@ onCreate()"; you seem to have code outside any method, which wouldn't compile. Therefore I can't suggest a specific place for the above line of code. However, my guess is that the right place to do it would be in the `success()` method. (Also, you should probably check the response status before assuming you have a valid `Restaurant` object.)

Comment: I use btn onClick() case R.id.btn:
                if (!rest.isBookmarked()) {
                    postBookmark(); // call retrofit
                } else {
                    ll_bookmark.setEnabled(false);                    
                }
                break; what wrong?

Comment: @Tr.Buu - You should set the enabled state of the button as soon as you detect the a new `Restaurant` object. You usually would not change the enabled state when you are processing the click event. (Note that if `ll_bookmark` is the button with id `R.id.btn`, then there would seem to be no way to re-enable the button.)

Comment: hi how to check isBookmarked() is not null. Restaurant res = new Restaurant(); if (res.isBookmarked!=null ) { ... } Operator '!=" cannot be applied to 'boolean','null'

Comment: @Tr.Buu - `res.isBookmarked` is a `boolean` value. It can't be compared to `null`. You can test it with `if (res.isBookmarked) { ... }` or `if (!res.isBookmarked) { ... }`. (You can also use `if (res.isBookmarked == true) ...` but the `== true` part is completely redundant and as a matter of style is usually omitted.)